# C# client lib for Mongodb: Will it run against Mongodb 3.x?

Tags: mongodb

We have an app that uses the C# Mongodb client lib from mongo, version 1.1.0.4184

This code currently runs against mongodb 2.6.4

We would like to stand up a new mongodb server, the current version (3.2.11). Will our code run against newer mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you mean by "will it run". The [MongoDB v1.1.0.4184 C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/releases/tag/v1.1.0.4184) was released in June, 2011 and dates to roughly the MongoDB 1.8 server release timeframe. This driver version is certainly no longer tested or supported, and will not be fully compatible with newer server features like the WiredTiger storage engine (default in MongoDB 3.2+) or SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication (default in MongoDB 3.0+).

The MongoDB documentation includes a reference table with recommended version(s) of the drivers for use with a specific version of MongoDB: [C#/.NET Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/#compatibility).

If this is a production system I would strongly recommend taking the time to update and test a supported version of the C# driver for use with MongoDB 3.2 (eg. the v1.11 C# driver). I suspect it is very likely you will encounter fixed (or novel) bugs/behaviour using a driver that is more than five years old. Your application won't be able to take advantage of many of the newer server features, and this obsolete driver predates specifications such as standard [Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM)](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst) behaviour.

That said, assuming you aren't using any features the driver isn't aware of your code may continue to run (or at least *appear to run*) successfully. In my opinion doing so is a high risk deployment strategy.

Comment: Thank you! We avoid mongodb for critical data, this is a log storage system.  We will stand up the new mongo server on 2.6.x o 2.8.x, as we do not want to revisit the mongo related code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am using it, but however we have to chek on specific features, which you were using. using MongoDB latest driver is much better in terms of latest features and there are few features were removed(like 'eval()').